# React navigation return to previous screen immdiately

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Trying to add navigation to React Native app with Redux and Saga. It work for one screen but when adding AppNavigator like this one it behaves strange

```
import HomeScreen from '../screens/fake/HomeScreen';
import LoginScreen from '../screens/fake/LoginScreen';
import SplashScreen from '../screens/fake/SplashScreen';

export const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Splash: SplashScreen,
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Login: LoginScreen
});
```

Each screen is control like this one:
class HomeScreen

```
 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          title="Go to Login"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')}
        />
        <Button
          title="Go to Splash"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Splash')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

i.e. contains only button that should navigates to another screen. And it does. But after that happens event `Navigation/NAVIGATE` that return user to previous page.

First event `Navigation/NAVIGATE` contains correct route key. But second occurence - `Navigation/COMPLETE_TRANSITION` (more exact: `{type: "Navigation/COMPLETE_TRANSITION", key: "StackRouterRoot"}`) return user to previous screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't really understand your problem. Let say that you have two screen: A and B. When you are on screen A and you press 'go to B' it navigates to B and then go back to A immediately ?

Comment: @Théodvn yes, exactly.

Comment: Do you have a `DrawerNavigator` in your navigation flow ? Would be nice to have more details about your code.

Comment: Only navigator specified in post. No other navigators.